# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1-a\cosh(\alpha x)}{(\cosh(\alpha x)-a)^2}\cos(\beta x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration, hyperbolic-functions

I would like to solve the following improper integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1-a\cosh(\alpha x)}{(\cosh(\alpha x)-a)^2}\cos(\beta x)\,dx$$

where $a$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real constants. The constant $a$ is so that $0<a<1$.

I tried to evaluate this integral by contour integration. Because $0<a<1$, we can write $a$ as:

$$a=\cos\phi,\,\phi\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

So, the integrand functions has poles of second order at $z=i(\pm\phi+2k\pi)/\alpha$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now a contour at the complex plane should be thought. I considered a semicircunference centered at the origin with a radius $R\to \infty$. A problem appears, which is to define $R$ as a sequence $R_n$, so that the arc doesn't intersect the poles. This is not straightforward due to the existence of $\alpha$ in $\frac{2k\pi}{\alpha}$. Is there a simpler way to evaluate this integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radii do not have to change continuously, one can take a sequence of contours which lie between the consecutive poles. Let $\alpha > 0, \,\beta > 0$,
$$f(x) = \frac
 {1 - \cos \phi \cosh \alpha x}
 {(\cosh \alpha x - \cos \phi)^2} e^{i \beta x},$$
then the residues in the upper half-plane are
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{x = i (\phi + 2 \pi k)/\alpha} f(x) =
\frac \beta {i \alpha^2} e^{(-\phi - 2 \pi k) \beta/\alpha},
\quad k \geq 0, \\
\operatorname*{Res}_{x = i (-\phi + 2 \pi k)/\alpha} f(x) =
\frac \beta {i \alpha^2} e^{(\phi - 2 \pi k) \beta/\alpha},
\quad k \geq 1$$
and evaluating the sums gives
$$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \,dx =
\frac
 {2 \pi \beta \cosh \frac {(\pi - \phi) \beta} \alpha}
 {\alpha^2 \sinh \frac {\pi \beta} \alpha}.$$

Comment: Shouldn't the residuals be:

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z = i (\pm\phi + 2 \pi k)/\alpha}f(z) =\frac{\beta}{i\alpha^2}\left(1\pm i\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cot\phi\right)e^{-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}(\pm \phi+2k\pi)}$$
?

Comment: Let $x_0 = i \phi/\alpha$, then
$$\frac 1 {(\cosh \alpha x - \cos \phi)^2} =
-\frac {\csc^2 \phi} {\alpha^2 (x - x_0)^2} -
\frac { i \cos \phi \,\csc^3 \phi} {\alpha (x - x_0)} + O(1), \\
(1 - \cos \phi \cosh \alpha x) e^{i \beta x} = \\
e^{-\beta \phi/\alpha} \sin^2 \phi +
i e^{-\beta \phi/\alpha} \sin \phi \,
 (\beta \sin \phi - \alpha \cos \phi) (x - x_0) + O(|x - x_0|^2).$$
The residue is $a_{-2} b_1 + a_{-1} b_0$.